# How to use React Native Animate to change view flex from 0 to 1

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have two views inside another view which has default flexDirection style so it is columnar. When the user clicks on an item in the bottom view (marked options below), I want the top view to animate to to be equal sizes with the bottom view and display the details of the selected option.

```
state = {
    animation: new Animated.Value(0)
}

...

<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <Animated.View style={{ flex: this.state.animation}}>
      {...details}
  </Animated.View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
      {...options}
  </View>
</View>
```

I am using the below method to change the value to grow the flex to 1.

```
onPress = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.animation, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1000
    }).start()
}
```

The issue I am running into is there is no animation, it just instantly appears no matter the duration I set.

Comment: have you tried to set the base `flex` size to 100 instead of 1? of your container View and the other fixed view?

Comment: you could also try to use percentages or `Dimensions`...

Comment: And try to animate flex from 0 to 100. I am curious now :)

Comment: 0 to 100 did the same thing, it just appears instantly instead of animating

Comment: it seems to work for me: https://snack.expo.io/Byu8w6-Um

Comment: Can flex be animated finally ? I can't set the height https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/106556986?noredirect=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me on expo:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

state = {
    animation: new Animated.Value(0)
}

onPress = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.animation, {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 1000
    }).start()
}

  render() {
    return (
     <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 100}} onPress={this.onPress}>
       <Animated.View style={{ flex: this.state.animation, backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
       </Animated.View>
       <View style={{flex:100, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://snack.expo.io/S1t5OaWL7

But I guess yes safer to animate `height` for performances. Not sure how `flex` is interpreted.

Comment: Youre right, and I found why it wasn't working for me. After the animate function, I was doing `this.setState({ animation: new Animated.Value(100) })` so that later I could reverse the animation to hide the details. What I needed to do was use the callback to set the state after the animation had performed. `Animated.timing(...).start(() => { this.setState({ animation: new Animated.Value(100)}) })`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm not sure if flex can be animated, however you can use height instead of flex. you can use Dimensions.get('window').height to grab the values, and animate based on that.

Comment: I believe it'd be `Dimensions.get('window').height`